# selected in select option give wrong attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to display a select with all the option of my enum and change the value to update my database.
To do so:
I have an enum:

```
export enum SubscriptionEnum {
    DAILY= 'DAILY',
    ANNUAL= 'ANNUAL',
    HALF-YEARLY = 'HALF-YEARLY ',
    QUARTERLY = 'QUARTERLY ',
    MONTHLY = 'MONTHLY ',
}
```

In my .ts file i create my enum var:

```
SubscriptionEnum = SubscriptionEnum ;
```

And then i display the option in my .html:

```
<p>{{client.subscription}}</p> // here it display what is registered in my db, in this case "ANNUAL"
<label for="subscription">Subscription:</label>
<select #subscriptionid="subscription">
   <option value="{{option.key}}"
           *ngFor="let option of SubscriptionEnum | keyvalue">
           {{option.value}}
   </option>
</select>
```

This example give me the select with all option and the value change in the view page when i clicked on a new option.

Then, i add the (change) in the select to call a method that change the content of the client subscription in the db. I did it like that:
.html:

```
<p>{{client.subscription}}</p> // here it display what is registered in my db, in this case "ANNUAL"
<label for="subscription">Subscription:</label>
<select (change)="changeInfo(subscription )" #subscription id="subscription">
   <option value="{{option.key}}"
           *ngFor="let option of SubscriptionEnum | keyvalue">
            {{option.value}}
   </option>
</select>
```

In my changeInfo i send the event and take the event.id and the event.value to update my db and it works because the select option change when i click on it and the `<p>{{client.subscription}}</p>` that is a value of my db take the good value.

Then i wanted to add a selector so my option value take directly the good value and this is not working ...
I add it like that:

```
<p>{{client.subscription}}</p> // here it display what is registered in my db, in this case "ANNUAL"
    <label for="subscription">Subscription:</label>
    <select (change)="changeInfo(subscription )" #subscription id="subscription">
       <option value="{{option.key}}"
               selected="{{option.key == client.subscription}}"
               *ngFor="let option of SubscriptionEnum | keyvalue">
                {{option.value}}
       </option>
    </select>
```

This give highlight me my sentence and tell me "Wrong attribute method" and when i reload my page my

div contains the good value which is "ANNUAL" but my option is equal to QUARTERLY. If i click to change the option, the good value will be saved in my db but the display of my select selector will be wrong.

What do i not understand ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between two similar Angular syntaxes:

```
selected="{{option.key == client.subscription}}"
```

and

```
[selected]="option.key == client.subscription"
```

There are both **property bindings** but the former assigns **interpolated value** to property.

It means that even in case of falsy values `selected` property will get `true`;

```
el.selected = 'false'
```

because `string` is a truthy value in js.

So you can consider the following options:

- **Use correct property binding:**

  ```
   [selected]="option.key == client.subscription"
  ```
- **Use `value` binding on `<select>` tag instead:**

  ```
   <select #subscription id="subscription" [value]="client.subscription">
     <option value="{{option.key}}"
         *ngFor="let option of SubscriptionEnum | keyvalue">
         {{option.value}} {{option.key == client.subscription}}
     </option>
   </select>
  ```